# How to read a series of number from a text file and write to new line using python?

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python and i am using python 2.7. I have a text file as follows

```
123455555511222545566332221565656532232354354353545465656545454541245587
```

I Want  to read this line and write each number in new line.

expected output as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
1
1
2
2
2
5
4
5
5
6
6
3
2
2
2
1 
.
.
.
.
7
```

How to read and write this to another file ?

Comment: What did you try so far and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: It would be great that if you can specified the python version that you are using.

Comment: @EmmanuelArias I am using Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.txt:

```
123455555511222545566332221565656532232354354353545465656545454541245587
```

and then:

```
logFile = "list.txt"

with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.read()     
for line in content:
    print(line)
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
1
1
2
2
2
5
4
.
.
.
5
5
8
7
```

EDIT:

```
logFile = "list.txt"   

with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.read()
    with open('output.txt', 'w')as f2:
        for line in content:
            print(line)
            f2.write(line + "\n")
```

output.txt:

```
1
2
3
4
5
5
5
5
5
5
1
1
2
2
.
.
. 
5
5
8
7
```

Comment: Thank you, i got the output as expected, but if i write the output to another file, it is writing same as the input file (like rows not  like column )

Comment: @ThehalfarisedPheonix I have edited the answer to add the functionality of adding it to another `txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all characters in this string.

```
line = "123455555511222545566332221565656532232354354353545465656545454541245587"
for c in line:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a file `test.txt` with:

```
123455555511222545566332221565656532232354354353545465656545454541245587
```

Take care that not exist a new line on the end of the file. If exist when you print you will have an empty line.

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for b in list(f.readline()):
    print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is to write each content in new line in another file.

```
with open('logfile.txt','r') as f1:
    with open('writefile.txt','w')as f2:
        read_data=f1.read()
        for each in read_data:
            f2.write(f'{each} \n')
```